# django 2.1 how to fetch value from db and assign it to foreign key

Tags: django

i am new to python django, i found it a bit challenging to fetch data from database and assign it to foreign key. i am using a postgres database.

model:

```
      class Company (models.Model):
           author = models.ForeignKey ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
           comapny_name = models.CharField ( max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

      class owner (models.Model):
           company = models.ForeignKey ( Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
           owner_name = models.CharField ( max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )
```

how should i go about it as i dont want to pass the value of FK through URl instead i want to query the value and assign it during form processing. Each User is allowed to create one company only so i want to assign comoany_name which is related to the user that h created the company name and assign it to the FK.

views:

```
      def createownerform (request):
         q = Company.objects.all()
         if request.method == 'POST' :
             form = ownerform( request.POST )
             if form.is_valid ( ) :
                 instance = form.save ( commit = False )
                 instance.company_id = q.id
                 instance.save ( )
                 return redirect ( 'str_dashboard' )
         else :
             form = businessmodelform ( )
         return render ( request , 'str_business.html' , { 'form' : form } )
```

Comment: What model is the businessmodelform for?

Comment: The way you defined the `Company` model, one `User` can have multiple `Company` instances. If you really want only one company per user, then you might want to use a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: appologies the businessmodelform is a typo i will correct it, i will change the foreign key to one to one field, now how do i query the ownerform view to fetch the company name for the user and assign it to FK

Comment: which user? `request.user`?

Comment: in the createownerform view

Comment: If you have 1-to-1 field, `company = request.user.company` is the company for the `user`. But be careful, if the `user` hasn't got a company this will throw an error that you should catch. Then `instance.company = company` is the way to set the relationship. You use the objects in Django, not the id. So don't do `instance.company_id...` it's bad practice.

Comment: i will give it a shot and will update you.

Comment: just one question do i need to add @login_required for each view am writing or no

Comment: If you only allow logged in users to access that view, yes.

Comment: it is going to be a view with card an he click on add a pop up window will appear for him to fill the data

Answer (score 0):

`q = Company.objects.all()` can't be right. It's a queryset, and will return a list of all the Company objects. But you want just ONE company so you can assign `instance.company_id = q.id`

Maybe you mean

```
q = Company( ).save   # to create a new Company with all defaults
q = Company( kw=value, ... ) # to create with specified values for fields
q.save() # so it gets an id
```

or

```
q = get_object_or_404( Company, kw=value, ...)
```

where `kw = value` identifies a unique company object to be queries out of the DB  and refers to company details parsed  in the invoking `urls.py`

Comment: i am trying to avoid passing the value through URl and i want to get the value from database and assign it to the FK, i tried dirk solution but it is not working

Comment: In that case you'll have to show us `ownerform`. You can include `company` in its fields, and Django should generate a pulldown selection from all available Companies.

Comment: The concept is I don’t want the user to select but the company he is creating is automatically assigned to the fk

Comment: So you have a form that reads in sufficient fields to create a company object and to identify an existing or to create a new owner object? Or the company owner is guaranteed to be the current logged-in user?

Comment: here is what am trying to do , first a user is created, then the user create a company which is related to the user, after that the user will assign company owner or owners and those owners are related to the company so the FK in owners to be automatically related to that company. later own i want to do a check that if the user has created a company is redirected to dashboard so preventing him from going to the company creation view but he can still update the owner or owners.